# Regular expression non-capturing group character length

Tags: regex, regex-group, counting, floating

I'm trying to generate a regular expression with the next pattern.
A number, of a maximum of 16 digits, that can have or not a comma inside, never at the beginning, never at the end.
I tried this:

```
^(?:\d+(?:,{1}\d+){1})$
```

The problem is that I can't count the result of a group {0,16}.
This is a list of numbers that should fit the expression:

> 123,34
>   1,33333333
>   1222222233

Example numbers that shouldn't fit:

> 1111,1111,1111
>   ,11111
>   11111,
>   11111111111111111111111111111,111111111111111 (more than 16
>   characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex flavour supports lookahead assertions, you can use this:

```
^(?!(?:\d{17,}$|[,\d]{18,}$))(?:\d+(?:,\d+)?)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33hlv)

I removed the superfluous `{1}` and made the group with the fraction optional.

The negative lookahead assertion `(?!(?:\d{17,}$|[,\d]{18,}$))` is checking your length requirement. It fails if it finds 17 or more digits till the end OR 18 or more digits and commas till the end. That I allow multiple commas in the character class here is not a problem, that there is only one comma is ensured by the following pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the length before that or using `^(?=[\d,]{1,16}$)(?:\d+(?:,\d+)?)$`

That is a lookahead that checks the length before doing the real match.